# Gitlab Notifications : No emails sent when I'm assigned to an issues with On Mention notification level set

Tags: gitlab

I've changed my notification setting on gitlab to On Mention, but I don't receive any emails when I'm assigned an issue. Is this a limitation of the On Mention email scope, or is there another setting I can change in order to receive these emails?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the `On mention` settings, you only receive emails when you are mentioned in a comment, specifically using the `@username` syntax.

For your needs, I suggest switching to the `Participating` notification level.